# Error in the flutter.gradle: Cann't run project

Tags: flutter, gradle

```
[+230100 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug
[ +101 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +5 ms] * Where:
[   +1 ms] Script '/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1100
[        ] * What went wrong:
[   +1 ms] Java heap space
```

Can not run flutter project.What to do?

Comment: can you add flutter doctor here

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.5.3, on Linux Mint 19.1 4.15.0-162-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at google-chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.63.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)